# Akka durable mailbox results in dead letters

Tags: akka

First, I am not an Akka newbie (been using it for 2+ years).  I have a high throughput (many millions of msgs/min/node) application that does heavy network I/O. An initial actor (backed by a `RandomRouter`) receives messages and distributes them to the appropriate child actor for processing:

```
private val distributionRouter = system.actorOf(Props(new DistributionActor)
  .withDispatcher("distributor-dispatcher")
  .withRouter(RandomRouter(distrib.distributionActors)), "distributionActor")
```

The application has been highly tuned and has excellent performance. I'd like to make it more fault tolerant by using a durable mailbox in front of `DistributionActor`.  Here's the relevant config (only change is the addition of the file-based mailbox):

```
akka.actor.mailbox.file-based {
    directory-path = "./.akka_mb"
    max-items = 2147483647

    # attempting to add an item after the queue reaches this size (in bytes) will fail.
    max-size = 2147483647 bytes
    # attempting to add an item larger than this size (in bytes) will fail.
    max-item-size = 2147483647 bytes
    # maximum expiration time for this queue (seconds).
    max-age = 3600s
    # maximum journal size before the journal should be rotated.
    max-journal-size = 16 MiB
    # maximum size of a queue before it drops into read-behind mode.
    max-memory-size = 128 MiB
    # maximum overflow (multiplier) of a journal file before we re-create it.
    max-journal-overflow = 10
    # absolute maximum size of a journal file until we rebuild it, no matter what.
    max-journal-size-absolute = 9223372036854775807 bytes
    # whether to drop older items (instead of newer) when the queue is full
    discard-old-when-full = on
    # whether to keep a journal file at all
    keep-journal = on
    # whether to sync the journal after each transaction
    sync-journal = off
    # circuit breaker configuration
    circuit-breaker {
        # maximum number of failures before opening breaker
        max-failures = 3
        # duration of time beyond which a call is assumed to be timed out and considered a failure
        call-timeout = 3 seconds
        # duration of time to wait until attempting to reset the breaker during which all calls fail-fast
        reset-timeout = 30 seconds
    }
}

distributor-dispatcher {
    executor = "thread-pool-executor"
    type = Dispatcher
    thread-pool-executor {
        core-pool-size-min = 20
        core-pool-size-max = 20
        max-pool-size-min = 20
    }
    throughput = 100
    mailbox-type = akka.actor.mailbox.FileBasedMailboxType
}
```

As soon as I introduced this I noticed lots of dropped messages.  When I profile it via the Typesafe Console, I see a bunch of dead letters (like 100k or so per 1M).  My mailbox files are only 12MB per actor, so they're not even close to the limit.  I also set up a dead letters listener to count the dead letters so I could run it outside the profiler (maybe an instrumentation issue, I thought?).  Same results.

Any idea what may be causing the dead letters?

I am using Akka 2.0.4 on Scala 2.9.2.

Update:

I have noticed that the dead letters seem to have been bound for a couple of child actors owned by `DistributionActor`.  I'm not understanding why changing the parent's mailbox has any effect on this, but this is definitely the behavior.

Comment: Any update on this that you can share?

Comment: Unfortunately I have never resolved this.